How to detect Google Play Pre-Launch Report context?
We've been using code like this to detect when our Google Play app is running in the Pre-Launch Report and Firebase Test Lab (FTL) environments: How to detect if the app is running on Google Play Pre-Launch report devices?
If we detect FTL context, we remove startup UI (including Privacy Consent screens) so the test automation can get to the meat of the app faster.
However, I have reason to believe that Google Play's App Approval process now also runs on FTL devices, which means that when Google is reviewing the app, they consider the lack of Privacy consent a Policy Violation.
So really we need to be able to detect the Pre-Launch report context, not the wider context of Firebase Test Lab.
Any suggestions?  We've considered writing code to detect random taps all over the screen, but if there's a more straightforward method, then that's obviously preferred.
